# Activity hangs while restarting the application

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-analytics

So here is the link of the application:-[Nearpeer-Offline messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nearpeer.app)

So After integrating firebase, sometimes while i am restarting this application i got stuck at first activity (mainactivity), its hang and after 10-20 sec later, error comes "application not responding" and app closes.
I already ask question before here :- [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927740/app-not-responding-after-integrating-firebase-analytic)

But didn't get good response response.
Here i am providing an MainActivity code:-

```
package com.nearpeer.app;

/** 
 *
 * Wifi-Direct based multi-user chat application
 *
 */

import java.util.Locale;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;

/**
 * The app's main entry point. Holds 2 fragments: {@link ChatSearchScreenFrag} and {@link ChatHistoryScreenFrag}.
 * The 1st fragment offers to scan for new chat groups and users. The 2nd offers to view chat history.
 */
public class MainScreenActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener 
{
    private AlertDialog mDialog=null;           
    private OnClickListener AlertCheckBoxClickListener=null;  //used to handle check-box click events for a dialog

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;  //adapter for the tab view. Contains all the frags
    ViewPager mViewPager; //a layout widget in which each child view is a separate page (a separate tab) in the layout.
    //both fragment will initialize these references when they're created:
    public ChatHistoryScreenFrag mHistoryFrag = null;    
    public ChatSearchScreenFrag mSearchFrag = null;

    boolean isServiceStarted = false;
    boolean wasWifiDialogShown = false;

    static int mDisplayedFragIndex = 0;
    public static long ChatRoomAccumulatingSerialNumber=0;
    public static String UniqueID=null;
    public static String UserName = ":>~";                //setting a default user name
    static boolean isToNotifyOnNewMsg = false;            //defines if notifications should be shown on arrival of new messages
    static int RefreshPeriodInMs = 30000;                 //defines the peer refresh period

    private boolean mIsRunForTheFirstTime=false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

        //FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

        /*Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);*/
        try {

            InitializeTabHandlerAndAdapter();

            if (!isServiceStarted && ChatSearchScreenFrag.mService == null) {
                startService(new Intent(this, LocalService.class));
                isServiceStarted = true;
            }

            getPrefs();  //get the shared prefs

            //Happens only when the app is run for the very 1st time on a device
            if (MainScreenActivity.UniqueID == null) {
                UserName = new String(Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID)); //get a unique id
                UniqueID = new String(UserName);
            }//if

            //Remove the title bar for out entire app
            getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Soory! Try after some time.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 10);
            toast.show();
        }

    }//end of onCreate()

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        //check if this activity was launched by the b-cast receiver after a wifi shutdown

        try {
            boolean isToDisplayWifiDialog = getIntent()
                    .getBooleanExtra(Constants.WIFI_BCAST_RCVR_WIFI_OFF_EVENT_INTENT_EXTRA_KEY, false);

            if (isToDisplayWifiDialog && !wasWifiDialogShown) {
                new EnableWifiDirectDialog().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MyDialog"); //show a dialog
                wasWifiDialogShown = true;
            }

            //if this app is run for the very 1st time, we want to launch the settings activity first.
            if (mIsRunForTheFirstTime) {
                //launch the preferences activity
                startActivity(new Intent(this, QuickPrefsActivity.class));
                mIsRunForTheFirstTime = false;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Soory! Try after some time.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 10);
            toast.show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        savePrefs(); //save the preferences
    }//end of onPause()

    private void InitializeTabHandlerAndAdapter()
    {
        // Set up the action bar (enable tab display). 
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the two
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() 
        {
                    @Override
                    //if a tab was changed by a swipe gesture
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {   
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position); //update the tab bar to match the selected page
                        mDisplayedFragIndex=position;   //update the index of the currently displayed frag
                        if (position==1)  //if the view has moved to the history fragment:
                        {
                            mHistoryFrag.loadHistory(); //reload the history list view
                        }
                        invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    }
                });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) 
        {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }//for
    }//end of InitializeTabHandlerAndAdapter()

    /**
     * Used to modify menu item according to the app's state
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        //Check wifi state.
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if(mWifi.isConnected()||wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
            ChatSearchScreenFrag.mIsWifiDirectEnabled = true;

        }

        //if the wifi-direct is disabled, we want to disable the chat room creation option
        menu.getItem(0).setEnabled(ChatSearchScreenFrag.mIsWifiDirectEnabled);

        //if this menu is opened when the chat search is active:
        if (mDisplayedFragIndex==0)
            {
            //hide the 'delete history option:
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete_all_history).setVisible(false);  
            }
        else  //history frag is active:
            {
            //show the 'delete history option:
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete_all_history).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem( R.id.clear_ignore_list).setVisible(false); 
            }

        return true;
    }


    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    Handler FirstTimeMenuUpdater = new Handler() 
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            MainScreenActivity.this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };


    /**
     * Called only once when the app starts
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_screen_menu, menu);

        FirstTimeMenuUpdater.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 500);

        return true;
    }//end of onCreateOptionsMenu()


     @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
         {
             switch (item.getItemId())
                {
                    case R.id.action_settings://setting was clicked
                    {
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, QuickPrefsActivity.class));
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.action_create_new_chat_room: //exit app was clicked
                    {

                        mDialog =CreatePublicChatCreationDialog();
                        mDialog.show();

                        AlertCheckBoxClickListener= new OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {

                                AlertDialog dialog = MainScreenActivity.this.mDialog;
                                EditText ed = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.choosePassword);
                                boolean b= !ed.isEnabled();
                                ed.setEnabled(b);

                            }
                        };

                        CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxSetPassword); 
                        ch.setOnClickListener(AlertCheckBoxClickListener);                  
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.clear_ignore_list: //exit app was clicked
                    {
                        if (mSearchFrag!=null)
                            mSearchFrag.ClearIgnoredUsersList();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.feedback: //exit app was clicked
                    {
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, FeedbackActivity.class));
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.about: //exit app was clicked
                    {
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutusActivity.class));
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.action_exit: //exit app was clicked
                    {
                        kill();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.action_delete_all_history: //delete all history was clicked
                    {
                        mHistoryFrag.DeleteAllHistory();
                        break;
                    }
                }//switch

            return true;
        }//end of onOptionsItemSelected()


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) 
    {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());   
    }//end of onTabSelected()

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction)
    {
    }

    /**
     * A FragmentPagerAdapter that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
    {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) 
        {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) 
        {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            Fragment fragment=null; //will hold the relevant fragment to be returned

            switch (position)
            {
            case 0:
                fragment = new ChatSearchScreenFrag();  //create a new chat search fragment
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new ChatHistoryScreenFrag();  //create a new history display fragment
                break;
            }

            return fragment;
        }//end of getItem()

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return 2;       // Show 2 total pages.
        }

        //Returns the title for each tab
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) 
        {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.main_screen_tab1_title).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.main_screen_tab2_title).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }//end of class



    /**
     * Called when the refresh button in the chat search fragment is clicked
     */
    public void onRefreshButtonClicked (View v)
    {
        mSearchFrag.onRefreshButtonClicked(v); //call the frag's method
    }//end of onRefreshButtonClicked()


    /**
     * Reads the saved preferences
     */
    protected void getPrefs()
    {             
          SharedPreferences prefs  = getPreferences(0);
          ChatRoomAccumulatingSerialNumber = prefs.getLong(Constants.SHARED_PREF_CHAT_ROOM_SERIAL_NUM, 0);
          UserName = prefs.getString(Constants.SHARED_PREF_USER_NAME, null);
          UniqueID = prefs.getString(Constants.SHARED_PREF_UNIQUE_ID, null);
          isToNotifyOnNewMsg = prefs.getBoolean(Constants.SHARED_PREF_ENABLE_NOTIFICATION, false);
          RefreshPeriodInMs = prefs.getInt(Constants.SHARED_PREF_REFRESH_PERIOD, 10000);
          mIsRunForTheFirstTime = prefs.getBoolean(Constants.SHARED_PREF_IS_FIRST_RUN, true);
    }//end of getPrefs(){       

    /**
     * Saved the shared preferences
     */
    protected void savePrefs()
    {
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
          editor.putLong(Constants.SHARED_PREF_CHAT_ROOM_SERIAL_NUM, ChatRoomAccumulatingSerialNumber); //save to current SN
          editor.putString(Constants.SHARED_PREF_USER_NAME, UserName);
          editor.putString(Constants.SHARED_PREF_UNIQUE_ID, UniqueID);
          editor.putBoolean(Constants.SHARED_PREF_ENABLE_NOTIFICATION, isToNotifyOnNewMsg);
          editor.putInt(Constants.SHARED_PREF_REFRESH_PERIOD, RefreshPeriodInMs);
          editor.putBoolean(Constants.SHARED_PREF_IS_FIRST_RUN, false);
          editor.commit();
    }//end of savePrefs()

    /**
     * Calls the kill() method of {@link ChatSearchScreenFrag}, resets all static variables,
     * calls the system's garbage collector and finishes.
     */
    public void kill(){
        savePrefs();    
        mSearchFrag.kill();  //close the entire app (service and welcome socket)


        //we'de like to reset all static variables in our app:
        ChatActivity.mIsActive=false;
        ChatActivity.mMsgsWaitingForSendResult=null;
        ChatSearchScreenFrag.mService=null;
        ChatSearchScreenFrag.mIsWifiDirectEnabled=false;
        ChatSearchScreenFrag.mIsConnectedToGroup=false;
        ChatSearchScreenFrag.mManager = null;
        ChatSearchScreenFrag.mChannel = null;
        LocalService.mNotificationManager=null;

        //Indicates to the VM that it would be a good time to run the garbage collector
        System.gc();    

        finish();         //close this activity
    }//kill()


    private AlertDialog CreatePublicChatCreationDialog()
    {
        // This example shows how to add a custom layout to an AlertDialog
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.public_chat_creation_dialog, null);
       return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)

        .setTitle("Create A New Room")
        .setView(textEntryView)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.settings_icon)

            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    boolean isPassword=false;
                    String password="";
                    String roomName=null;

                    EditText ed = (EditText) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.choosePassword);

                    //gets password if exists
                    isPassword= ed.isEnabled();
                    if(isPassword){password=ed.getText().toString();}

                    //gets rooms name
                    ed = (EditText) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.chooseRoomsName);
                    roomName=ed.getText().toString();

                    //if the room's name is invalid:
                    if(roomName==null || roomName.length()<1){
                        // pop alert dialog and reload this dialog
                                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainScreenActivity.this)
                                .setTitle("Missing name error")
                                .setMessage("A room must have a name")

                                //yes button setter
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {mDialog.show();}})//setPositive

                                 .setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener(){
                                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog){mDialog.show();}})

                                 .show();
                        //end of alert dialog 
                    }//if

                    else{//there is a room name             
                        //the room is ready to be created
                        //call the service and create a new public chat room
                        if (password.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                            password=null;

                        ChatSearchScreenFrag.mService.CreateNewHostedPublicChatRoom(roomName,password);

                    }//else
                }//onClick dialog listener


            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {}

            }).create();
    }//end of ShowPublicChatCreationDialog()

}//end of class
```

Though it is commercial application but i have to share this because this issue must be solve by any how.

Here is the log cat what i got while stucking at screen:-
      [logcat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByVD0epCPa6ANTM0T3puYV9Zbmc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Error logs ? Share if you have any

Comment: In your gradle build dependencies do you have only `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.x.x.` or other Firebase and Play Services libraries also?  Are you including all of Play Services using `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.x.x`.  If so, that can be a problem.

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not an efficient debugging mechanism. Try to [reproduce the problem with a minimal amount of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll have a much better chance at getting useful help.

Comment: 1. I Already share a link of log cat. @Eenvincible

Comment: Yes i have only com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.x.x. dependencies in my gradle @qbix

Comment: I can suspect you are probably doing too much work on your UI thread; I would move some of them to a background thread